# Add the product description to WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

How to add product description/content of single product page (not the short description) to WooCommerce **new order** email notification?

I need to know specific written description of my products as most of them are almost same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are targeting a specific email notification, first we need to get the **Email ID** to target the "New Order" email notification. The only way is to get it before and to set the value in a global variable.

Then in a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_order_item_meta_end`** action hook, we display the product description exclusively for New Order email notification.

Here is that code:

```
 ## Tested on WooCommerce 2.6.x and 3.0+

// Setting the email_is as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'the_email_id_as_a_global', 1, 4);
function the_email_id_as_a_global($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
}

// Displaying product description in new email notifications
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'product_description_in_new_email_notification', 10, 4 );
function product_description_in_new_email_notification( $item_id, $item, $order = null, $plain_text = false ){

    // Getting the email ID global variable
    $refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
    $email_id = $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'];

    // If empty email ID we exit
    if(empty($email_id)) return;

    // Only for "New Order email notification"
    if ( 'new_order' == $email_id ) {

        if( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) { 
            $product_id = $item['product_id']; // Get The product ID (for simple products)
            $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']); 
        } else {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            
            if( $product->is_type('variation') ) {
                $product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );
            }
        }

        // Get the Product description (WC version compatibility)
        if ( method_exists( $item['product'], 'get_description' ) ) {
            $product_description = $product->get_description(); // for WC 3.0+ (new)
        } else {
            $product_description = $product->post->post_content; // for WC 2.6.x or older
        }

        // Display the product description
        echo '<div class="product-description"><p>' . $product_description . '</p></div>';
    }
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

> **Code Update and Error explanations in `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` action hook:**
>
> **[PHP Warning for woocommerce_order_item_meta_end (Mike Joley)](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12717)**

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's working. I am receiving emails with product description now. However, after placing order, this message is displayed on the page:

Warning: Missing argument 4 for product_description_in_new_email_notification() in /home/cbllookbook/public_html/wp-content/themes/you-child/functions.php on line 22

which is function product_description_in_new_email_notification( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ){

should i rearrange the arguments? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do this; however, I set the value of argument 4 to NULL so that I can get rid of the message.

Comment: This only works on admin emails, not customer emails.

Comment: @Michelle No sorry, it works on all emails. Now this code is old and it can be shortened, removing compatibility with prior versions of Woocommerce 3.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec Any idea how i can do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76634373/custom-product-description-in-woocommerce