# Add product short description to WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Based on [Add the product description to WooCommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564232/add-the-product-description-to-woocommerce-email-notifications/43566405#43566405) answer, how to add **product short description** instead of product description *(which tend to be longer)* to both email notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display short description on email notifications sent to admin, use the following:

```
// Displaying short product description in email notifications sent to admin
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'product_description_in_new_email_notification', 10, 4 );
function product_description_in_new_email_notification( $item_id, $item, $order = null, $plain_text = false ){
    // Only on email notifications
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) return;

    $product_obj = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );
    $short_descr = $product_obj->get_short_description();
    
    if( ! empty($short_descr) ) {
        // Display the product description
        echo '<div class="product-description"><p>' . $short_descr . '</p></div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.