# Custom Product Description for WooCommerce orders and email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I need to modify the product description to be displayed on all customer notifications. So, I have tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_description_so_15127954', 10, 2 );
function wc_checkout_description_so_15127954( $other_data, $cart_item ) {
    $post_data = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    $custom = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'order_description', true );        
    $other_data[] = array( 'name' =>  $post_data->$custom );
    return $other_data;
}
```

But this code changes the description everywhere. I **only** need it changed after the product has been purchased, to display a custom description on order emails and payment receipts etc... without changing the product description or short description

**Note :** This issue is related to the displayed description on orders, email notifications, PayPal and CC receipts. The description could be generated from the product description OR from the short description, so any solution should filter/modify both of them just for the display in orders, email notifications, PayPal and CC receipts.

---

Update - Code addition:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'custom_description_custom_field' );
function custom_description_custom_field() {

    $args = array(
        'id' => 'order_description',
        'label' => __( 'Order Description', '$text_domain' ),
        'class' => 'product-description-field',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'Custom Order Description Shown on PayPal, Credit Card, reciept, checkout & order email.', '$text_domain' ),
    );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_description_custom_field' );
function save_custom_description_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $title   = isset( $_POST['order_description'] ) ? $_POST['order_description'] : '';

    $product->update_meta_data( 'order_description', sanitize_text_field( $title ) );
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: I'd first check if the relevant templates don't offer more specific hooks that could be used to manipulate it only for those places. If not, then I suppose you'd have to make your code above "context aware" somehow. Not sure how far the available conditional tags - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/, https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/ can get you, it might need  checking for specific URL paths as well. (And then that would beg the question again, how it will work, if anything gets triggered in the background via a cron or something.)

Comment: I've checked the checkout, emails and order templates and can't even find where the description is added. It might be included with the $order variable somehow.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes, i have now coded the custom fields for input but not sure which hook should be used to change the default output for the product name and description. Was thinking about using woocommerce_before_calculate_totals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have improved the existing code of your addition, changing the text input field with a text area, and changing the hook of your last function:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'custom_description_custom_field' );
function custom_description_custom_field() {

    $args = array(
        'id' => 'item_description',
        'label' => __( 'Custom description', '$text_domain' ),
        'class' => 'product-description-field',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'Custom Order Description Shown on PayPal, Credit Card, reciept, checkout & order email.', '$text_domain' ),

    );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_custom_description_custom_field' );
function save_custom_description_custom_field( $product ) {
    $title = isset( $_POST['order_description'] ) ? $_POST['item_description'] : '';
    $product->update_meta_data( 'item_description', sanitize_text_field( $title ) );
}
```

Now we need, first to display it on the checkout page (as required):

```php
// Checkout: Display "Item description" custom field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'checkout_custom_field_item_description_display', 10, 2 );
function checkout_custom_field_item_description_display( $item_qty, $cart_item ) {
    if( $item_description = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('item_description') ) {
        $text_domain = 'woocommerce';
        $item_qty .= sprintf('<br>
        <div class="item-description"><span>%s</span><br> 
        <small>%s</small></div>', __('Description:', $text_domain), $item_description );
    }
    return $item_qty;
}
```

Then save that "Item description" custom field as order item metadata, allowing to display it on all orders and email notifications:

```php
// Save "Item description" custom field value as order item metadata and display on orders / emails
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_custom_fields_as_order_item_metadata', 10, 4 );
function save_custom_fields_as_order_item_metadata( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( $item_description = $values['data']->get_meta('item_description') ) {
        $item->add_meta_data('item_description', $item_description);
    }
}

// Have a readable "meta key" label name replacement
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    if ( $display_key === 'item_description' ) {
        $text_domain = 'woocommerce';
        $display_key = __('Description', $text_domain);
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Tested and work for checkout, orders and email notifications.

**Remaining** *(untested)*: You need to test that on PayPal and CC receipts. If it doesn't work for those, you should ask a new question, specifically for PayPal and CC receipts.

Comment: Thanks but the only problem here is the default product description is already displayed on the buyers PayPal > Activities > Payments Sent > Transaction Details > Order Details screen. I need to filter or remove this as your code adds a custom description. This is why i thought using the woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook to change the description might work.

Comment: The right hook to be used for PayPal is `woocommerce_paypal_args`... [Here are a list of all related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_paypal_args) – So now you can search for some useful answers and try to make your own code attempt. If it doesn't work, then ask a new question providing that code, taking care to explain, with clarity, what is the issue you are facing, with all required details. Good coding.

Comment: This is what i have coded in addition to your work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76642347/custom-description-for-woocommerce-notifications